# How to identify relationship between 3 dimensions?

Tags: many-to-many, relationship, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to identify relationships between 3 relations. I have a large dataset whith 3 dimensions.

- Debitor ID
- CVR ID
- KF ID

These are all listed in one long list where each row (Debitor, CVR and KF) is unique. However the Debitor ID can appear more than one time with two different CVR ID, but maybe with the same KF ID. The same thing can happen with the other two dimensions. That means that there is many to many relationships between the two.

Is it possible to make some kind of code and input the dataset to it, and make it loop through all rows and find the relationsships between all rows and assigning it a unique Client-Group?

I attempted to do a sketch of how the data is, and how the relationships are - and what I want to get in the end.
[Screenshot with explanation of data relations and how it should be grouped in the end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omw33.png)

So how do I make a unique ID that groups related rows?

Answer (score 0):

With pandas in Python:
`df['unique_id'] = df.groupby(['DEBITOR', 'CVR', 'KF']).ngroup()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#enumerate-groups

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not work. It gives an id to each unique row, which gives me 10 different ids instead of the 3 different ids I was looking for.

I Imported this data
Debitornummer CVR KF
1 12 21
2 13 21
3 13 22
3 14 23
4 12 24
5 14 0
6 15 25
6 16 25
7 17 25
7 17 0
8 18 26

And Pandas outputted this:
# Debitornummer CVR KF unique_id
0 1 12 21 0
1 2 13 21 1
2 3 13 22 2
3 3 14 23 3
4 4 12 24 4
5 5 14 0 5
6 6 15 25 6
7 6 16 25 7
8 7 17 25 9
9 7 17 0 8
10 8 18 26 10